# away3d WireframeMaterial: setting the wire's width

Tags: flash, away3d

I am having a difficult time setting the width of a WireframeMaterial.
Things were working well until I upgraded to from 2.5 to 3.6

I am doing:

var mat = WireframeMaterial(0xff0000, {width:4, alpha:alphaValue});

but that's not working at all
the width is still set to 1 !!

any idea how that might be resolved?

thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you mean is not width, but thickness of a WireframeMaterial.
You also want to change the alpha value of the wireframe.

The solution is to set the properties `thickness` and `wireAlpha` of WireframeMaterial like this:

```
var material:WireframeMaterial = new WireframeMaterial(0xff0000, {thickness: 4, wireAlpha: alphaValue});
```